# javascript select range from ordered array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, indexing, filter, where-clause

Let's assume we have a large array of objects, ordered by a specific field range_id:

```
const points = [
{"x":3,"y":4,"range_id"=0},
{"x":7,"y":9,"range_id"=0},
{"x":5,"y":1,"range_id"=1},
{"x":2,"y":6,"range_id"=1},
{"x":12,"y":0,"range_id"=2},
...
{"x":73,"y":61,"range_id"=5000},
{"x":21,"y":87,"range_id"=5000},
];
```

now I would like to do the equivalent of

```
points.filter(pt => pr.range_id=1);
```

But since the array is supposed to be large, I want to use a function that is aware that the array is sorted by range_id which acts like an index.

In SQL, there would be an index on range_id.

In C++20, we could use `ranges::equal_range()`.

How can it be done in Javascript ?

Comment: Not sure if i understand you question, but If you want to get the range you can use something like `points .indexOf('xxx')` and `points.lastIndexOf('xxx')`. this will give you the range.

Comment: I think you did understand, and your suggestion makes sense, except it would take O(N) and not O(log(N)) compute time. In other words it doesn't take full advantage of the array being ordered by "range_id".

Comment: @LudovicAubert "I wonder how an array of arrays behaves performance wise, versus a flat array" it depends. Arrays in JS can be both sparse and mixed content; In the worst case they are represented in memory by a hash map. And they usually allocate more space in memory than their current length, in case you add elements to the array. And JS' JIT Compiler optimize the specific use case. So an array of arrays may be optimized differently to another occurrence. Generally speaking.

Comment: Sounds like an array of 5000 arrays might not be a good idea from a memory usage standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data is sorted you can do a binary search which runs in `O(log(N))` time.

make two searches, one to find the start of the range, one to find the end.

```js
// supposed to find the index of the first element that matches the predicate.
// expects that ALL elements after that also match!
function binarySearch(array, predicate) {
  let lo = 0, hi = array.length;
  while (lo < hi) {
    const mid = (lo + hi) >> 1;
    if (predicate(array[mid], mid, array)) {
      hi = mid;
    } else {
      lo = mid + 1;
    }
  }
  return lo;
}


// generate some data
var data = [...Array(10).keys()]
  .flatMap(id => Array(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5 + 1)).fill(id))
  .map((range_id, index) => ({ range_id, index }));

const search = 4;
// find the start of the range
const start = binarySearch(data, item => item.range_id >= search);
// find the end of the range
const end = binarySearch(data, item => item.range_id > search);

console.log(data);
console.log(start,end);
console.log(data.slice(start,end));
```

Comment: nice, but I am surprised that we have to implement this ourselves. For example C++20 supplies equal_range() to do that.

Comment: I have tried your code with a large json array of 100k lines loaded into the js script client side. The search is so fast in the browser you don't even notice.

Answer (score 1):

As I have mentioned in my comment you can use `points.indexOf('xxx')` and `points.lastIndexOf('xxx')` to find your ranges.

It will take `O(N)` and not `O(log(N))` as you wanted.

I have checked all available arrays method and as far as I know, In JS you don't have any method for your wanted behavior in `O(log(N))`.

You can check all available methods in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@unscopables).

---

If you want to achieve something like this you can loop the array and for each new item (that you haven't detected yet) find the last index of that entry using a binary search.

Thinking about the worst case my solution may be slower than `O(Log(N))`, but for most cases I think it is better than `O(N)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you change the model to an object and the range id will be the key and the value will be the points within this range in an array.

Example:

```
const points = {
  '0': [{"x":3,"y":4}, {"x":3,"y":4}],
  '1': [{"x":5,"y":1}, {"x":2,"y":6}]
}
```

Then you can access them by the key e.g. the range_id. Hope that helps

Comment: that's a great idea. The numbering '0', '1', ... could be removed to get an array of arrays.

Comment: I wonder how an array of arrays behaves performance wise, versus a flat array. The answer would help decide if this solution is worth considering. If it were C++, arrays of arrays cannot be stored in contiguous memory, whereas flat arrays would if items were (like here).

Comment: As you wish. I suggested that when you construct the sorted data to use object instead of flat array. Then you would not need to loop through the whole array but use the range id to select what you need. Performance wise must be way more efficient. You could also use Map to achieve the same. It is all up to you

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly you can use the array method [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
// note that in javascript === not = means is equal to 
points.find(pt => pt.i === 1);
```

> In SQL, there would be an index on i.

All array operations in javascript expose an index, [you need to pass it in as a second argument to the function.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters)

```js
points.filter((pt,index) => ... );
```